# Multiple route between two location in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I need to show multiple routes in my iOS application that uses Maps API.
I am able to draw single route but how I can draw multiple routes?

I am using google direction api to get single route

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.6353080000,77.2249600000&destination=28.5355161000,77.3910265000&mode=walking&sensor=false

Also in ios 5 Native Map application of iPhone show two popup saying Route1 and Route two and when user touch that selected route get highlighted .So can we also do same??

Comment: Hi there,  welcome to SO. Its pretty typical to show an example of what you've already done. This is usually important because it shows people that you've done your homework and clarifies exactly where your misunderstanding is.

Comment: I agree an example of how you did your first route and some more info about what libraries you are using would be helpful to help you. I took the liberty to guess you are using maps api.

Comment: A tip is also that in ios6 the google maps is not enabled by default just so you know. It has been replaced with apple Maps. I think its still downloadable trough app stor though.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson But i am not doing related to specific map like google or apple.I am drawing a line using lat,long. And Might be i am wrong but i believe it will work same on any map.because my concern is lat long

Comment: Okay I just wanted to raise your awareness.

Answer (score 0):

> alternatives (optional), if set to
>   true, specifies that the Directions
>   service may provide more than one
>   route alternative in the response.
>   Note that providing route alternatives
>   may increase the response time from
>   the server.

From [The Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters)

You need to add in your query link alternatives=true

see: [Find the number of routes between two places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095435/find-the-number-of-routes-between-two-places)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is Code**

**write this code**

```
#pragma mark - MapView Delegate

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

        //   [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.annotation];

            NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true", self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, [[self.dictData valueForKey:@"latitude"]doubleValue],[[self.dictData valueForKey:@"longitude"]doubleValue]];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

                NSArray *routes = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];

                NSDictionary *firstRoute = [routes objectAtIndex:0];

                NSDictionary *leg = [[firstRoute objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0];

                NSDictionary *end_location = [leg objectForKey:@"end_location"];

                double latitude = [[end_location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
                double longitude = [[end_location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

                MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                point.coordinate = coordinate;
                point.title = [leg objectForKey:@"end_address"];
                point.subtitle = @"Event Destinations !!!";

                [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

                NSArray *steps = [leg objectForKey:@"steps"];

                int stepIndex = 0;

                CLLocationCoordinate2D stepCoordinates[1 + [steps count] + 1];

                stepCoordinates[stepIndex] = userLocation.coordinate;

                for (NSDictionary *step in steps) {

                    NSDictionary *start_location = [step objectForKey:@"start_location"];
                    stepCoordinates[++stepIndex] = [self coordinateWithLocation:start_location];

                    if ([steps count] == stepIndex){
                        NSDictionary *end_location = [step objectForKey:@"end_location"];
                        stepCoordinates[++stepIndex] = [self coordinateWithLocation:end_location];
                    }
                }

                MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:stepCoordinates count:1 + stepIndex];
                [self.mapView addOverlay:polyLine];

            }];
    }

#pragma mark - Custom Methods

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204/255. green:45/255. blue:70/255. alpha:1.0];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 10.0;

    return polylineView;
}
```

Comment: You may want to improve your code formatting in your answer. To Block quote code, indent every line by 4 spaces. Using a backtick " ` " only works well for words or small bits of code. See the ? button when you edit for more code formatting tips!