# How to get multiple routes between two locations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, core-location

With the following code .i'm getting only one route.Actually it has three routes,but unable to show 3 routes with this code.How can I do this?

```
NSString *baseUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Hyderabad&destination=Sangareddy&key=%@&alternatives=true",key];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse
*response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if(!connectionError){
            NSDictionary *result        = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *routes=[result objectForKey:@"routes"];

            NSDictionary *routesdict=[routes objectAtIndex:0];

            NSArray *temproutearr=[[[routesdict objectForKey:@"legs"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"steps"];
            _pointsarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(int i=0;i<temproutearr.count;i++){
                [_pointsarr addObject:[[[temproutearr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"polyline"]objectForKey:@"points"]];
                    }
            GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

            for (NSString *polyStr in _pointsarr) {
                GMSPath *p = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:polyStr];
                for (NSUInteger i=0; i < p.count; i++) {
                    [path addCoordinate:[p coordinateAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
      polyPath.map= _mapView;
        }
    }];
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095435/find-the-number-of-routes-between-two-places?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the number of routes between two places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095435/find-the-number-of-routes-between-two-places)

Comment: @jigar Didn't get it....it says to add  alternatives=true in query Link..but no change in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSString *baseUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Hyderabad&destination=Sangareddy&key=%@&alternatives=true",key];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse
*response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if(!connectionError){
        NSDictionary *result= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *routesArray = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
for (NSDictionary *routeDict in routesArray) {
    NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
    NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
    GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
    polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    [polyline setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    polyline.map = _mapView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've added `alternatives=true` in query Link you will get 3 routes.

```
NSArray *routes=[result objectForKey:@"routes"];//routes count will be3
```

Then instead of storing first index in `NSDictionary *routesdict` try to draw the routes using `for loop`.

**Swift**

```
for item in 0..<(jsonData.valueForKey("routes") as! [[String:AnyObject]]).count
{
   let pathStr = ((jsonData.valueForKey("routes") as! [[String:AnyObject]])[item]["overview_polyline"] as! [String:String])["points"]!
   let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: pathStr)
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
   polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
   polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
   polyline.tappable = true
   polyline.map = self.mapView
   })
}
```

Comment: Then i'll get polyline points for each route ,so should i add all points to GMSpath and then to GMSpolyline right?

Comment: You'll get 3 polyline points. Then you should create 3 GMSPath and 3 GMSPolylines. You can set different `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` to highlight particular polyline.